# why undefined error in the following backbone view codes?

Tags: backbone.js

```
const _ = require('underscore');

module.exports = (() => {
  const PANEL_HEADER_HEIGHT = 40;

  return Frame.extend({

  ...
    _handleSearch: _.debounce(ev => {
      if ( ev.keyCode !== 9 ) {
        const searchValue = $(ev.target).val();
        this.model.filterData(searchValue);
      }
    }, 1000),
   ...
})();
```

> this.model.filterData(searchValue); **converted to**
>   **undefined.model**.filterData(searchValue); in console.

Any idea?

Comment: what it is saying is that `this` is undefined. What are you expecting `this` to be referred to in that context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work if you re-write the method without using an arrow function.

https://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/2dt30fhb/

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    name: 'MY-VIEW',
    doStuff: _.debounce(function() {
        alert(this.name);
    }, 1000)
});

var view = new MyView();
view.doStuff();
// This will alert 'MY-VIEW'
```

The reason it's failing is because Babel will transpile the code to follow the ES6 spec.

```
module.exports = (() => {
  // this = undefined, because module.exports is global.
  return Frame.extend({
    // inherits this from above, undefined
    _handleArrowFunction: _.debounce(ev => {
      console.log(this);
    }),
    _handleRegularFunction: _.debounce(function() {
      console.log(this);
    })
  });
})
```

Look at the difference in how babel transpiles the code:

- [module.exports as an arrow function](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=%2F%2F%20module.exports%20is%20an%20arrow%20function%2C%20context%20is%20inherited%20from%20where%20the%20method%20is%20defined%0A%2F%2F%20which%20happens%20to%20be%20undefined%2C%20so%20any%20arrow%20function%20defined%20below%20will%20also%20be%20undefined.%0Amodule.exports%20%3D%20(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20x%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(this)%3B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20this%20will%20be%20undefined%0A%0A%20%20return%20Frame.extend(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20_handleArrowFunction%3A%20_.debounce(ev%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20_handleRegularFunction%3A%20_.debounce(function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D))
- [module.exports as a regular function](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=%2F%2F%20module.exports%20is%20a%20regular%20function%2C%20context%20is%20defined%20by%20the%20function%20itself%2C%20so%20it%20will%20be%20defined%0A%2F%2F%20although%20it's%20value%20might%20be%20Window%20if%20the%20function%20is%20on%20a%20global%20level%0Amodule.exports%20%3D%20(function()%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20x%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(this)%3B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20this%20will%20be%20inherited%20from%20context%20of%20module.exports%0A%0A%20%20return%20Frame.extend(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20_handleArrowFunction%3A%20_.debounce(ev%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20_handleRegularFunction%3A%20_.debounce(function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D))

You can read more about arrow functions and the `this` value here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Please include the babel examples inside your answer and provide the links as references.

Comment: Sorry, I was busy doing that